# Compatibility Google Maps Apis - TomTom Bridge

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tomtom

I have developed an Android app which uses Google Maps Apis; i need to run it in a TomTom Bridge (Android version 4.3).
Is there any restriction for using Google Maps Apis inside that device?
There is something wrong, because when I run the app in the TomTom, it crashes as soon as I try to open the map (managed through Google Maps).
I tested the app with different Android devices and it works fine.

Andrea

Comment: A TomTom Bridge? Running an Android app in a TomTom? I must have missed a lot!

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What's wrong? Can you explain me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from TomTom people:

Although TomTom Bridge runs Android (4.3), it is not a Google certified device, which means that our product does not support Google Services - which includes Google maps (you can access the maps in a browser, but you can't use the Google maps application).
The way customers approach this is by leveraging the onboard TomTom maps in their application instead. We have created the 'Map Library SDK' specifically for this purpose.